# Setting bar size in formattable

Tags: r, formattable

I am wonder if its possible reverse the size of the `color_bar` command in `formattable`, example:

```
library(formattable)

df = data.frame(Ranking = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10))

formattable(df, list(Ranking = color_bar("red")))
```

My table result is:

[image: table]

Is it possible get the largest bar in number `1` and the shortest bar in number `10`? I have a `Ranking` column where the `1` number is the best ranking.

**EDIT1**

Other solution that work for me is omit or remove the number in the `color_bar`.

**EDIT2:**

Other question : How I could center the header?

My code:

```
formattable(df, align =c("c"), list(Ranking= color_bar("red")))
```

Comment: Do you plan to use it in Rmarkdown?

Comment: Yes I am using Rmarkdown and knitr

Comment: I have an idea, if you aren't hurry - I'll try to help a little later.

Comment: I did it, one moment ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

````
```{r, include=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(formattable)

InvProp = function(x) (1.05 - ((x) / (max(x)))) #inverse proportion
#make our formattable
df = data.frame(" " = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 15), check.names=FALSE)
table2 <- formattable(df, list(" " = color_bar("red", InvProp)))
```

#you can modify title style with html and css, as you wish
<center>
<caption>My formattable</caption>
</center>
`r table2`
````

[image]

---

**An addition**

```
library(formattable)
library(kableExtra)

InvProp = function(x) (1.1 - ((x) / (max(x)))) #inverse proportion
df = data.frame(names = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10), check.names=FALSE)

df %>% 
     mutate(
         "names" = color_bar("red", InvProp)(names)) %>%
    kable("html", escape = F, align = c("r"), col.names = NULL) %>%
    kable_styling("hover", full_width = F) %>%
    column_spec(1, width = "5cm", color = "white")
```

After you can customize it as you wish. Good luck.

[image]

Comment: Nice solution! Thanks

Comment: exist some posibility of change the number color: white maybe??

Comment: @RodrigoBadilla I did it

Comment: Great! thanks for your time!